# Loading gif animation before the content of iframe loads from the server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, blockui, updateprogress

I need to show a "Loading" gif animation in my application before the loading of iframes . I tried in 3 methods .

1. using Updateprogress in update panel . 
Update progress works well but causes the iframes to blur after loading in the browser.

2. using BlockUI using jquery

3. using css. In all the methods,there specified a time limit for the loading of gif animation. But in my application,the iframe gets the report from the pentaho server and the loads. If I manually specify a time say 3000 seconds, it differs from the content loading of iframes.I couldnt find the exact time limit for the animation. how to get the content loading time of iframes from server and implement this animation.
My code source for Updateprogress and BlockUI methods:
http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos
css method implementaion as 
Source : jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin and mycode as

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#alert").click(function () {
    jAlertload();
    setTimeout(hideit,seconds); 
     });
     });
     function hideit() {
            $("#popup_containerload").remove();
            $("#popup_overlayload").remove();
        }
        beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
        function pageloadingtime() {
         afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
         var seconds = 0;
         seconds = (afterload - beforeload) / 1000;   
         seconds1 = seconds * 1000;    
         }
        window.onload=pageloadingtime;
    </script>
```

css

```
#popup_containerload {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;min-width: 10px; 
    max-width: 600px; 
    background:  none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position:absolute;color: #000; top: 547px;
    z-index: 99999;
}    
#popup_contentload {
    padding: 1em 1.75em;margin: 0em;
}    
#popup_contentload.alert 
{
    position:absolute;height:100px;width: 100px;top: 55px;
    background: url(ajax-loader-5.gif) 10px 16px no-repeat;
}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Servers don't know how long it would take for the client to load a particular resource. This time is basically the time it takes the resource to reach from server to client through Internet.

A better approach for you would be to show the image upon calling for the resource i.e. `jAlertload()` and look for the load event of the content. Once the content is loaded, you can hide your `.gif`

The load event can be triggered using `$(document).ready(....);` event in you iframe content.

An even smoother approach would be to hide the content of iframe through CSS and show it after it is completely loaded and meanwhile hide the `.gif` image.